# How to stub private methods of a class under test by sinon

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing

I am trying to stub a private method in a class. I have searched in many blogs that have no right answers or not related to my concern. Can we stub private methods?

This is my code which uses the private method I want to stub:

```
public static async create(roleTO: RoleTO): Promise<RoleTO> {
        log.trace('Inside create method with roleTO: ', roleTO);
        roleTO.name = roleTO.name.trim();


     await this.validateIfRoleNameIsTaken(roleTO); //validateIfRoleNameIsTaken it is a private method. I am trying to stub this method


        let rolePO: RoleDocument = <RoleDocument>PoToConverter.getRoleTo2Po(roleTO);
        console.log(rolePO,'this is rolelPO');

        log.trace('Persisting Role: ', rolePO);
      rolePO = await rolePO.persist();
       console.log(rolePO._id,'tydtydytd');

        roleTO._id = rolePO._id;
        console.log(roleTO);
        return roleTO;


    }
```

This is the private method definition:

```
 private static async validateIfRoleNameIsTaken(role: RoleTO | RolePO): Promise<void> {
        log.trace(`Inside validateIfRoleNameIsTaken method with role: `, role);
        let RoleModel: RoleModel = <RoleModel>model(ROLE_MODEL);

        let existingRoles: RolePO[] = await RoleModel.findByName(role.name);


        log.debug(`Fetched following roles from storage: `, existingRoles);
        ValidationUtil.failIfMatchExists(role.name, existingRoles);
    }
```

Comment: Generally, you don't test private methods. Why do you need to stub the private method? Can you tell us more about what the method does and why it needs to be stubbed?

Comment: I am not directly testing a private method .when I call a method X(suppose) which is in turn calling the private method Y(suppose)  this has to be stubbed for me to get the expected result.

Comment: Just don't do that. Try to rethink your approach.

Comment: if you know any other approaches ,I will be  pleased if you let me know

Comment: What exactly does the method do? Could you please post its body? Maybe there's a way to mock something that this method depends on?

Comment: I have added the private method , I hope some one would help me

Comment: So it seems like you can change the behavior of this small method only by changing the behavior of `<RoleModel>model(ROLE_MODEL);` (which seems to not be a method so I guess it's easier to stub) and/or `ValidationUtil.failIfMatchExists(role.name, existingRoles);` (which seems like a static method so it is easier to stub). And if I were you, that's the direction I would follow: stub the public external classes/helpers this method depends on instead of the method itself. That way you can control the behavior of the method pretty easily